# Why here in Protoypical inheritance Child class method is not called instead of Parent Class Method?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I have a `Shape` as parent class, and `Circle` as a child class. Using prototypical inheritance in Javascript, I have overridden the parent class `duplicate` method.

When I run the following code, calling the `duplicate` method on the child object (`circle`), instead of executing the child class method, it is calling the parent class (`Shape`) method.  And when I comment out the parent class `duplicate` method, it is calling the child class method. This is the opposite of what I expected. I thought it should give precedence to the child method, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong....

```js
function Shape(color) {
  this.color = color;
  this.duplicate = function () {
    console.log("This is shape duplicate method");
  };
}

function Circle(radius, color) {
  Shape.call(this, color);
  this.radius = radius;
  this.draw = function () {
    console.log("This is Circle draw method");
  };
}

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

Circle.prototype.duplicate = function () {
   console.log("This is biggg cirlce after duplication");
};

const circle = new Circle(4, "pink");
console.log("Radius of Circle is: ", circle.radius);
console.log("Color of Circle is: ", circle.color);
circle.duplicate();
circle.draw();
```

After running above code I got as output:

> Radius of Circle is:  4
>
> Color of Circle is:  pink
>
> This is shape duplicate method
>
> This is Circle draw method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and/or problem. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and/or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you perform `circle.duplicate()`, JS first searches for `duplicate` on the `circle` object itself, and if it can't find it, it then looks for it on the circle's prototype, if it can't find it there either, it searches for it on the prototype's prototype, and so on until it is able to find the `duplicate` property.

In the case of your `circle` object, you have two versions of the `duplicate` function, one as an own property on the `circle` instance itself and one of the circle's prototype object. The `duplicate()` function you want to invoke is located on the prototype, but you can't "reach" it, as the `duplicate` function on the circle itself gets invoked instead.

The reason why your `circle` instance has a duplicate function is due to calling your parent constructor when you perform  `Shape.call(this, color);`, which calls your `Shape` function that then adds the parent `duplicate()` function to your circle instance (`this`):

```js
this.duplicate = function () {
  console.log("This is shape duplicate method");
};
```

This function takes precedence over the function on your prototype, as it is on the circle object itself.

Typically, you would define functions on the prototype rather than on the instance itself. Currently, your parent creates a new function every time a new parent instance is created. Instead, you can add your `duplicate()` function to your parent's prototype to avoid creating a new function object each time your create a Parent object. Moreover, adding it to the prototype avoids you adding a `duplicate()` method directly to your `circle` object when you call the parent constructor from your child `Cricle` constructor function, which you won't be adding `duplicate` to your the `circle` instance itself, which will allow `circle.duplicate()` to call the duplicate method defined on the circle's prototype:

```js
function Shape(color) {
  this.color = color;
}
Shape.prototype.duplicate = function () {
  console.log("This is shape duplicate method");
};


function Circle(radius, color) {
  Shape.call(this, color);
  this.radius = radius;
}

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

// Override
Circle.prototype.duplicate = function () {
 console.log("This is biggg cirlce after duplication");
};

Circle.prototype.draw = function () { // move the draw function to the prototype so we only create "one" function that can be shared amongst all circle objects (saves on memory)
  console.log("This is Circle draw method");
};

const circle = new Circle(4, "pink");
console.log("Radius of Circle is: ", circle.radius);
console.log("Color of Circle is: ", circle.color);
circle.duplicate(); // This is biggg cirlce after duplication
circle.draw();
```

On a side note, I see that you're using newer (well, not *so* new these days) features of JS such as `const`, but are still working with old function constructors. These days JS has its own [`class` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which implement and handles a lot of the overhead of the above code for you. You can rewrite the above-using classes like so:

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  duplicate() { // methods defind in a `class` automatically get added to the object's prototype
  console.log("This is shape duplicate method");
  };
}

class Circle extends Shape { // `extends` is how we perform inheritance using classes
  constructor(radius, color) {
    super(color); // similar to Shape.call(this, color)
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  
  draw() {
    console.log("This is Circle draw method");
  };
  
  duplicate() {
   console.log("This is biggg cirlce after duplication");
  };
}

const circle = new Circle(4, "pink");
console.log(circle);
console.log("Radius of Circle is: ", circle.radius);
console.log("Color of Circle is: ", circle.color);
circle.duplicate(); // This is biggg cirlce after duplication
circle.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborated answer. Actually I am preparing for interview so I am studying" what is prototypical inheritance", yes using ES6 classes this implementation is easy. Thanks for your guidance.